# where can I track site visits over time?

Tags: discussion

I know that the site stats (on the left side of the front page) include visitors/day.  I'm guessing that is averaged over some time frame.  Is there a place that I can see the number of visitors on each particular day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see that information on the Quantcast site:

http://www.quantcast.com/academia.stackexchange.com

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, they don't make that data public. The number you see is pretty good for gauging trends, though.